# Am I permitted to use an LGPL library without releasing the source to the rest of my application, if I dynamically reference the library?

Tags: lgpl

I am a bit confused as to what I am/am not allowed to do with a LGPL Library that I intend on using in a small scale commercial C++ Application that I am developing. My current understanding, although I don't know if I am correct, is that I am permitted use the library without releasing the source to the rest of my application if I dynamically reference the library. Does anyone know if this is correct? Are there any restrictions as to how I reference the library? Thank You! I am not a native English speaker and don't understand the licence entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use the unmodified library with your own proprietry code - so long as your user can exchange the LGPL library for their own version (this normally means using a dynamic linked library = dll or so)

If you do modify the library you are required to release the source code *of the library* with your changes.

The only extra complication would be if you used ideas/concepts from the source code of the library inside your own app - then your app could be a derived work . But normally there are no problems using an LGPL library with a commercial app - that was the idea of it.

Comment: If I add a reference to said DLL in my own project in Visual Studio, is this considered static or dynamic linking?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - not sure what you mean by a reference. If you simply link to the dll then no the project file doesn't become GPL. If you mean your make some sort of CLR reference assembly then that wrapper would be a modification to the LGPL

Comment: +1. Of course if the library were **GPL** rather than **LGPL**, this wouldn't be legal.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure either, because [implicit linking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/february/inside-windows-win32-portable-executable-file-format-in-detail) in C/C++ in Visual Studio requires linking against a .lib import library before you can link against a dll. LINK.exe can't link against PE binaries, so does that mean that LoadLibrary at runtime is the only option?